# How to resolve: compareTo >> cannot find symbol

Tags: java, object, interface, compare, compareto

This is for a homework assignment. However, I have coded the overwhelming part of my assignment. There is just this one roadblock. I am also new to Java, so my terminology may be a bit off.

So I have 5 types:
Provided by teacher:

- NameInterface, which is the interface file for Name
- Name, which uses 2 private Strings, first & last, for first and last name
- StudentInterface, which is the interface file for Student
- StudentTest, which is main method used for testing

Mostly provided by teacher, I just have to fix compareTo(). Everything else like constructors, fields, etc is done:

- Student, which uses fullName (which is a NameInterface) & String city

Name class has a compareTo() override that uses Java's built-in compareTo to compare this first & other first

```
  public int compareTo(Object other)
  {
  int result = last.compareTo(((Name)other).last);

  if (result == 0)
  {   
      // last names are equal; check first
     result = first.compareTo(((Name)other).first);
  }  // end if 

  return result; 
} // end compareTo
```

Student class has a compareTo() that uses Name class compareTo to compare this Name & other Name as well as this city & other city

```
  public int compareTo(Object other)
  {
  Student localStudent = (Student) other;
  int result = (fullName.getName()).compareTo((localStudent.getName()).getName());

  if (result == 0)
  {   
      // last names are equal; check first
     result = city.compareTo(localStudent.getCity());
  }  // end if 

  return result; 
  } // end compareTo
```

I try to call Student class's compareTo in StudentTest, but it says cannot find symbol.

```
  StudentInterface si = new Student();
  si.setCity("Kingston");
  NameInterface ni = new Name("Andrew","Pletch");
  si.setName(ni);

  StudentInterface si2 = new Student();
  si2.setCity("Kingston");
  NameInterface ni2 = new Name("Aram","Agajanian");
  si2.setName(ni2);
  System.out.println(" compare as (should be +ve) " + si.compareTo(si2));
```

error is:

```
StudentTest.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
  System.out.println(" compare as (should be +ve) " + si.compareTo(si2));        
                                                        ^
symbol:   method compareTo(StudentInterface)
location: variable si of type StudentInterface
1 error
```

My conclusion is that "Object other" does not comply with "StudentInterface". How can I resolve this? Thank you everyone.

Comment: Could you paste the full code to include important information (e.g., the full definition of the StudentInterface)?

Comment: Did you declare `int compareTo(Object other);` inside `StudentInterface`?

Comment: This means the interface `StudentInterface` does not specify a `compareTo` method. It seems that you only define one in the `Student` class.

Comment: Or, usually preferably, `StudentInterface extends Comparable<StudentInterface>`.

Comment: @chrylis Is correct, you should use the `Comparable` interface, but don't forget to update the signature of your implemented `compareTo` method (you will find out how ;)).

Comment: @Tsung-TingKuo What do you mean by full definition? And I pasted si and si2.

Comment: @DavidWallace & Pinkie
No the code my teacher gave us did not include that, I don't think that's the solution because I think we only modify Student.
I was under the impression any Interface methods MUST be done in class, but not vice versa.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ It IS the solution.  Try it.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It works.
I'd like to clarify--ALL methods you use in the class must be represented in the interface? I have some doubts about this because my teacher taught us we could have extra methods not mentioned in the interface.

Comment: Please don't edit your question title to tell us that your question was solved. Please  post an answer to that question instead and tell us how you've solved it.

Comment: @KartikChughヅ All methods that you use have to be represented *on the type of the variable*. You have a `variable si of type StudentInterface`, and so you can only use the methods declared on that interface.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add compareTo to the interface. All methods used have to be represented on the type of the variable. si is of type StudentInterface, so you can only used methods declared on StudentInterface.